# ngAnimate with ngHide fails to add 'ng-hide-animate' hook class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I have this case, where I want to apply animation to a DOM object with ngHide directive:

http://plnkr.co/edit/r4i7WbCepl2w9Svv0YHn?p=preview

In this example, I have this JSON objects array:

```
$scope.items = [
    {"key": 1, "values": []},
    {"key": 2, "values": [21, 22, 23]}, 
    {"key": 3, "values": [31, 32, 33, 34]}
];
```

This list is bound to a `<ul>` element which will show the keys of this list. When selecting an item of them, values should be displayed in another `<div>` with id detailsList. which will be shown using `ng-show="selectedItem"` statement.

Animation is added using CSS: `#detailsList.ng-hide`, according to Angular documentation of ngAnimate.

When selecting/deselecting the first item with no values, animation works well, but not with the items with values.

When inspecting detailsList element, I found that hook class: `ng-hide-animate` is not added during animation as described by documentation.

Is it a bug or I missed sth??

Comment: Have you included ngAnimate module in your app dependencies?
angular.module('appName', ['ngAnimate'])

Comment: @OriDrori if you'd click the plunkr he added, you'd see that he did include it

Comment: My poor old eyes missed the plunker.

Comment: I submitted this to angularjs team and they reported to be a bug. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12453

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and had been solved by AngularJS team in version 1.4.4

Check this Git issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12453

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write this animation by yourself, specially for ngRepeat

```
app.animation('.animation-ng-repeat', function(){
    return {
        leave : function(element, done) {
            element.slideUp({complete: done});
        },
        enter : function(element, done) {
            element.hide();
            setTimeout(function() {
                element.slideDown({complete: done});
            }, 50);
        }
    }
});
```

Then just add it to your ng-repeat as a CSS class.